# How to remove single and double quotes from string but keep it on specific apostrophe words

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, quote

So, i got the phrase:

> "And then, Vader said to Luke: 'Luke, I'm your father'."

I know that i can simply strip **all** quotes with something like:

```
let string = "And then, Vader said to Luke: 'Luke, I'm your father'.";
string.replace(/['"`]/g, '');
```

The thing is I want to keep the apostrophe on specific words like I'm(perhaps pass as a param to a function)
How can I do it?

Comment: Did my answer below solve the issue? If yes, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```js
let string = "And then, Vader said to Luke: 'Luke, I'm your father'.";
console.log(string.replace(/\b(')\b|['"`]/g, '$1')); // if in between word chars
console.log(string.replace(/([a-zA-Z]'[a-zA-Z])|['"`]/g, '$1')); // if in between ASCII letters
console.log(string.replace(/(\p{L}'\p{L})|['"`]/gu, '$1')); // if in between any Unicode letters
```

The point is to capture the `'` that is in between the chars that create the context where you want to keep the single quotation mark and then replace with a backreference to this first capturing group.

The `\b(')\b` part matches a `'` in between start/end of string or a non-word char and a word char while capturing the `'` into Group 1,  or (`|`) the `` ['"`] `` matches any of the three chars in the  character class in any other context. Since `$1`, backreference to Group 1 value, is always initialized as an empty string, replacing with it will always bring the expected result, it will  be either empty if `'` in between word chars is not matched, or it will contain the `'` to be kept.

The last line of code will support any Unicode letter since `\p{L}` matches any letter in any language, and it works thanks to the `u` modifier. Note it is not yet universally supported at the time of writing, but most major browsers and environments already support it.

Comment: If you want to keep apostrophes after numbers, such as when talking about decades, add `\p{N}` to your matcher:


    `var string = "Vader said to Luke: 'Luke, I'm your father and it's the 1970's'";`
    `console.log(string.replace(/([\p{L}\p{N}]'[\p{L}\p{N}])|['"\`]/gu, '$1')); // if in between any Unicode letters or numbers`